# From which timestamp of a YouTube video is the preview thumbnail taken?

Tags: youtube

In the YouTube overview page, the individual videos are displayed as still images showing a frame which was taken from that video.

Is there a way to find out from which timestamp of the video this preview thumbnail was generated?

Answer (score 3):

Any and none. YouTube doesn't use timestamps to determine which thumbnail to use.

[They use deep learning.](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/10/improving-youtube-video-thumbnails-with.html)

Comment: This answer would be better if you included the more relevant parts of the link in the answer itself in case the webpage goes down

Answer (score 1):

YouTube allows you to use a custom thumbnail once you have a verified account.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431?hl=en